# PHP target the same span

Tags: php, jquery

I have a page with 3 dropdowns, each outputting to a central span called “info”. What I want to do is have buttons in that output span bring up other date within the same span. So my question is how do I target the same span?
The code,

```
function autoSubmit1() {
$.post('dropoutput1.php', { name1: rr.Technology.value},
 function (output) {
    $('#info').html(output).show();
    });
}
```

successfully populates the info span.
Within the dropoutput1.php, the code,

```
echo '<FORM name="go" METHOD="POST" target="_self" ACTION="dropoutput2.php?name2=' . $row["Company"] . '"><INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="' . $row["Company"] . '"></form>';
```

does go to the correct data, but it opens in the full window and not within the info span. Any ideas?

Comment: post the html code of the info 'span' pplease

Comment: By the way, you should use lowercase html tags.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to insert a `form` in a `span`. Don't put block elements into inline elements. Your browser probably just moved the form after the span.

Change your `span#info` by a `div#info`. Use `display: inline-block` css property if you want to make it inline.

Comment: @paranoid yes probably... float, whatever ^^

Comment: I did the inline block but it did not work.  Also, I simplified my code to:       echo '<span class="newStyle1"><a href="dropoutput2.php?name2=' . $row["Company"] . '"><font size="3" color="red">' . $row["Company"] . '</font></a></span>';

Comment: Well "It did not work" is not very useful to help you. Do you have any error in console ? You should also update your question with the whole code (js and php)